# Toeplitz Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis

**Theorem:**

> Let $a_n$ be a real sequence convergent to $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Let
>   $c_{k,n}$ (where $1\le k \le n$) be a sequence such that:
>
> $$\quad \forall k \lim_{n \to \infty}c_{k,n} = 0$$ $$\quad \lim_{n \to
> > \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n c_{k,n} = 1$$ $$\quad \exists M>0 : \forall n\ \
> > \sum_{k=1}^n |c_{k,n}| \le M$$
>
> Then $\lim_{n \to \infty}s_n =a$, where $$s_n \equiv \sum_{k=1}^n
>  c_{k,n} \cdot a_k.$$

The author of my textbook begins by observing that if $a_n$ is a constant sequence then $$s_n=a\sum_{k=1}^n
 c_{k,n}$$ implying that $\lim_{n\to \infty}s_n=a.$ He then remarks that it is enough to consider the case when the sequence is equal to zero. I don't understand the reasoning behind this argument and would, therefore, be grateful if someone could explain this step in the proof. Here is the complete proof by the way. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a_n)_n$ converges to $a$ then the sequence $(a_n-a)_n$ converges to $0$. If we assume that the theorem holds for sequences converging to zero, we know that for
$$
s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{k,n} (a_k-a)
$$
we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n =0$. But you have also just proved that for
$$
s_n'= \sum_{k=1}^n c_{k,n} a
$$
we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n' = a$. Note that if we define
$$
S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{k,n} a_k = s_n +s_n',
$$
then we find $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = 0+a = a$. So the theorem holds in general.